# Can't mount old CD-ROM - ISO-13346 UDF format

Tags: mac, optical-drive

I have an old CD-ROM I'm trying to read using my external USB drive. After some time spinning, it mounts with a README.TXT file containing the text:

```
This disc contains a "UDF" file system and requires an operating system that supports the ISO-13346 "UDF" file system specification.
```

I've tried mounting using `mount -t udf` and `mount -t cd9660` but neither work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What macOS version are you running?

Comment: AFAIR macOS never played well with UDF. You *may* have more luck with running Linux in a VM and accessing the CD-ROM from there ("may" because I never tried this myself).

Comment: What @nohillside said.  I don’t think UDF was supported for a “whole” disk, but it could be read if it was part of a hybrid partition in both macOS and Windows (not sure about Linux).  The 9660 format UDF replaced was supposed to be universal (the “U” in UDF) but it failed at that goal.

Comment: @Thinkr Ventura 13.3.1

Comment: _UDF filesystem is supposed to be formatted on the whole media and not to the partitioned hard disk. Mac OS X systems enforce this rule and reject to automatically mount UDF filesystem unless it is formatted on the whole unpartitioned hard disk._ https://man.archlinux.org/man/mkfs.udf.8#WHOLE_DISK_VS_PARTITION

Comment: I really want a terminal solution. Using Disk Utility to mount worked for me on my UDF ISO.